# AngularJS re-applying filter inside controller doesn't update my content

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Update: i added an example here on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TZf22PPvpL5J8nzeHlsP?p=preview)

I have a problem with a filter that i try to re-apply inside my controller. This filter is inside a ng-repeat and nothing happen. (i think this is the problem)

Concept: i truncate a text and add a more button to show it all.

My template is like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
     <td>
         <ul>
              <li><a href="{[{ app.trackViewUrl }]}">{[{ app.trackName }]}</a></li>
              <li><strong>Description:</strong> {[{ app.description | characters:255 }]}
                  <a ng-click="changeLength(app)"><strong>More</strong></a>
              </li>
         </ul>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

ps: i removed all the part not relevant in the ng-repeat.

My controller:

```
$scope.changeLength = function (app) {
    var txt = app.description.length;
    var description = $filter('characters')(app.description, txt, true);
    return description;
};
```

i use this filter [truncate](https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-truncate)

```
angular.module('truncate', [])
   .filter('characters', function () {
      return function (input, chars, breakOnWord) {
        if (isNaN(chars)) return input;
        if (chars <= 0) return '';
        if (input && input.length > chars) {
            input = input.substring(0, chars);

            if (!breakOnWord) {
                var lastspace = input.lastIndexOf(' ');
                //get last space
                if (lastspace !== -1) {
                    input = input.substr(0, lastspace);
                }
            }else{
                while(input.charAt(input.length-1) === ' '){
                    input = input.substr(0, input.length -1);
                }
            }
            return input + '...';
        }
        return input;
    };
});
```

Filter is call and he send me back the description but is not applying the change in the DOM. What did i miss ?

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide some live example? like fiddle or plnkr?

Comment: @TiagoMoutinho ok i'll try later on the night.

Comment: @TiagoMoutinho I added a plunker we've just to code needed to run the example. http://plnkr.co/edit/TZf22PPvpL5J8nzeHlsP?p=preview